# Remove last occurrence of bracketed text in string

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string and I have to remove the last occurrence of parentheses using regex.

> **String:** "Programmer (C#) (3)"
>   **Result:** "Programmer (C#)"

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the match with empty string.

```
@"\([^()]*\)(?=[^()]*$)"
```

OR

```
@"\([^()]*\)(?!.*\([^()]*\))"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uN4lT5/7)

```
string replaced = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"\([^()]*\)(?!.*\([^()]*\))", "");
```

This won't work for the parenthesis which have the depth of more than 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "depth of more than 1"?

Comment: like `(((fgf)))`. Is this solution satisfies your needs?